# Is the implementation of TFDCustomConnection.ExecSQL bad and should it be corrected?

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-10.3-rio

This is from the `unit FireDAC.Comp.Client`:

```
function TFDCustomConnection.ExecSQL(const ASQL: String; AParams: TFDParams;
  var AResultSet: TDataSet): LongInt;
var
  oQry: TFDQuery;
begin
  oQry := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    oQry.Connection := Self;
    oQry.SQL.Text := ASQL;
    if AParams <> nil then begin
      AParams.BindMode := pbByNumber;
      oQry.Params := AParams;
    end;
    oQry.Open;
    Result := oQry.RecordCount;
  finally
    AResultSet := oQry;
  end;
end;
```

Main question: is there any sense in this `finally`? Do I understand it wrong or would it be the same to have `AResultSet := TFDQuery.Create(nil);` in the first place?

Additional question: shouldn't the parameter be `out` instead of `var`? The documentation says:

> AResultSet is an instance of TDataSet that ExecSQL fills with the data
> that the database management system returns as a response to your SQL
> statement.

I guess this frequently leads to memory leaks, because developers think they have to create that object first.

Comment: Internally out and var are the same thing. Whether that should be so is a different matter.

Comment: @Dsm Actually, this is not entirely accurate.  Managed type are "nil"ed out before being passed as an "out" parameters, but not when passed as a var.  Same for interfaces. Objects are not affected. (As of Delphi Seattle at least)

Comment: @KenBourassa, thank you for this correction. I was not aware of it.